# How to request input in controller from ajax in codeigniter4

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4

How to get data from ajax in controller CI4?

```
$this->request->getvar() <<< = null
```

This is the AJAX Call

```
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {
        const menuId = $(this).data('menu');
        const roleId = $(this).data('role');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/changeaccess",
            type: 'post',

            data: {
                menuId: menuId,
                roleId: roleId
            },

            success: function() {
                document.location.href = "/admin/roleaccess"; + menuId
            }
        });
});
```

This my input from view

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
 <?= check_access($role['id'], $m['id']); ?> 
 data-role="<?= $role['id']; ?>" 
 data-menu="<?= $m['id']; ?>">
```

Comment: For POST type request you should use FormData. Refer to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: Should this be $(this).attr('data-role') instead of $(this).data() ?

Comment: how to get the data in controller ??
$this->request->getvar('menuId'); ==  null

Comment: Since it is a post request you should use $this->request->getPost('var_name');

Comment: Yeessh aolve it thx u sirr ...